# Displaying data from multiple models on home page?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I'd like to display a summary of data from various models on my home page. There's a HomeController and a home/home.html.erb but no model. I was hoping it would be as simple as placing something like this for each model in the HomeController and then view, but nope, that doesn't work!

Controller:

```
 def load_tracks
 @tracks = Track.all
 end
```

View:

```
<% @tracks.each do |track| %>
<%= track.name %> - <%= track.isrc %>
<% end %>
```

Any pointers would be really appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your controller will have to look like this:

```
class HomeController < ApplicationController
    def home
        @tracks = Track.all # or this could come from a method
    end
end
```

And your view can be the same now. When rails sees a request it looks for the action with that name. So when you tried to go to `/homes/home` it went in to the `Homes` controller to find a `home` action and couldn't find it, so that's probably why it didn't work.

**EDIT** You shouldn't really have a "HomesController" anyways. A "PagesController" might make more sense. Check out [Michael Hartl's RoR tutorial book on the subject](http://ruby.railstutorial.org/chapters/static-pages#sec%3astatic_pages).

Comment: Also, make sure you configure your routes in config/routes.rb.  
    i.e.) match "homes/home" => "homes#home", :as => "homes_home"

Comment: Great, thanks. I had to change the def above to index but then created some methods to load the data I needed and entered them within the index def.

Comment: But you're all right about home/home.....typo on my part, it should have been home/index.

Comment: I have multiple roles (users), each kind of role will have their own homepage, I am using home_controller to redirect to different action (home_admin, home_user, home_another, etc.). is that a good practice?

Answer (score 2):

Let's say you have two models, Track and Playlist and you want to display information about them on the Home controller's index page.  In `app/view/controllers/home_controller.rb`

```
def index
  @tracks = Track.all
  @playlists = Playlist.all
end
```

then in the view, `app/view/home/index.html.erb`

```
<h1>Tracks and Playlists R Us</h1>
<p><%= "We have #{@tracks.count} tracks and #{@playlist.count} playlists." %></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

You migh also want to take a look at `Presenter`. It's a good and clean way to grab data from different models.

Here: http://railscasts.com/episodes?utf8=%E2%9C%93&search=presenter
and http://railscasts.com/episodes?utf8=%E2%9C%93&search=draper